# All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0,

Tags: android

All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 27.0.2. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.

Whatever API I use gives me the same error.

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

The android team has been working on migrating the support libraries to androidx. This allows you to mix and match better.

Backup your project and in android studio go to

Refractor > Migrate to AndroidX

Comment: Have your gradle api entries changed?

Comment: yes changed but it is showing me this error   ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Answer (score 0):

Add explicitly the library with the old version but with a new version number.

In your case `implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'` so you need to add:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
```

ie: Take the library from the second item, and implement it with the version number from the first.

Note: don't forget to press sync now

Now after changes your dependencies will look like this:

```
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
  implementation "com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0"
  implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0"
  implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
  implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'

  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```